# Powershell - get-childitem but only return directories that have items in them?

Tags: powershell

We have an ftp server with 30k+ directories on it and dozens of subdirectories deep. A bunch of the folders are empty.

Im trying to make a powershell script that'll export the list to CSV but if there are no items in any of the subdirectories then exclude it from the list.

Any help? My attempts arent working.

Comment: Why use PowerHell? I would use for example WinSCP script. https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting

Comment: I cant install anything all I can do is work with the tools I have access to.

Comment: I believe you can run WinSCP portable version install free FYI iirc. I assume you got what you needed but if you just want full file name of the files only in one column, then per below `Cpt.Whale` answer extend that to `Get-ChildItem "E:\" -Recurse -File | Select-Object -Property FullName | Export-Csv -Path "E:\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation;` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `-File` to only return file objects (and skip empty directories):

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\folder\' -Recurse -File
```

Comment: Extended for csv requirement example: `Get-ChildItem 'C:\folder\' -Recurse -File | Select-Object -Property FullName | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\export\test.csv' -NoTypeInformation;`

Answer (score 1):

Do a regular `Get-ChildItem` and filter it using `Where-Object`:

```
gci -recurse | ? {
    -not ($_.Attributes -band [IO.FileAttributes]::Directory) `
    -or `
    (gci $_.FullName).Count -gt 0
}
```

Conveniently, it seems that `gci <file>` returns one item (the file itself), so this can be simplified to:

```
gci -recurse | ? { (gci $_.FullName).Count -gt 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

To list only directories with a non-zero `Count`, use the
`-Directory` switch of
[Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1)
like this, to export to CSV :

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -recurse | ? {$_.GetFiles().Count -ne 0} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation list.csv
```

You may further select the properties of the result to include
in the CSV file by filtering through the
[Select-Object command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.3).